# How to find the inverse of the Piecewise Linear function

Tags: geometry, functions, linear-transformations

I have the following function:

$k_1x + b,                                    x < x_0$

$k_1x + b + k_2(x-x_0),                      x_0 \leq x < x_1$

$k_1x + b + k_2(x-x_0) + k_3(x - x_1),        x \geq x_1$

So the parameters are:

> $x_0, x_1, b, k_1, k_2, k_3$

I would like to invert this function changing the values of the parameters.

One idea is to invert the slopes $k_1$, $k_2$, $k_3$.

Would that be sufficient?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, first you should make sure that the function is one-to-one in the required set. And no, it's not sufficient so just change $k_1$ to $\frac{1}{k_1}$ etc. You also have to change the limit values, and make sure that there are no overlaps ...

Comment: I really meant reversing the sign of $k_1$ to $-k_1$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

In the three intervals, you have a relation of the form

$$y=ax+b,$$

which is inverted as

$$x=\frac{y-b}a.$$

What you have to do is

- to find the $y_k$ values corresponding to the $x_k$, which delimit the $y$ intervals,
- to obtain the $a_k,b_k$ coefficients in the three pieces.